# Display the original caller on stack trace when logging

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

I'm working on an angular project and I have another project linked through node modules.
I'm calling the `loggerService.log('something')` from the main application where `public log(message)` is in the **loggerService** of the linked project, the method **log** has `console.log(message);` which will log the message to the stack.

My problem is when it logs the message to the stack trace it refers to the line number of the **loggerService** in the linked project (in index.js) but I want to show the line number of the actual caller from my main application.

I have tried console.log.bind() but that didn't help either.

Declared the console as an ambient

```
declare var console: any;
```

Log method

```
public log(...args: any[]) {
    if (console && console.log) {
        this.event.next(...args);
        console.log.bind(...args);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions will be helpful :)

Comment: Post the code you used when you attempted using `.bind()` because that's correct and does work.  It'll just need fixing.

Comment: @Archer , I have updated the question.